# Android how to pass pointer on List and receive it back

Tags: java, android

I'm developing a simple Application. It has 3 buttons (start record, stop record, send info to the server). I want to record my voyage on the map, and I implemented it, but it works only when Activity is onResume(), so now I implementing sticky service, which will do exactly the same, but in the background. So service will fill `ArrayList<MapPoint>`, and then I have to receive it back somehow to my activity. It is not necessary to pass `ArrayList` to Service, but I have to receive it back to send it to the server in `onDestroy()` method. Please, help.

Answer (score 0):

I thinks you can put the value in shared preferences and then pull it back in the activity